# JPA: Save Map<String, Object> to table

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-mapping

My entity class looks like this

```
@Entity
class Item {
    String name; 
    ...

    Map<String, Object> properties; 
}
```

Where `Object` could be stored as an Json representation.

I've already tried storing it in two different tables like this `List<Property>` where property has key and value attributes. But this causes extra headache while converting to DTO.

Having a map seems to be natural representations. What are my options?

Comment: I do a similar thing to what you mentioned with List<Property> and it works well for me.

Comment: Define how Object is going to be stored. Using an `AttributeConverter`? or (better still) don't use Object and define its class.